# Jquery moving a image instead of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im trying to code up a script were if your mouse goes near the image the image will move.
Here is my source and live preview.
http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/4/
Has you can see once you move near the button it moves which is what i want.
But now i need to turn the button into a html form and turn the button into a image.
Is there any way to do that ? I am no good with jquery.

html

```
<button>button</button>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $("button").on({
        mouseover:function(){
            $(this).css({
                left:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
                top:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
            });
        }
    });
});
```

css

```
button{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

I own a pokemon online game. I want to grab a random pokemon from the db ( which i can do) and then have the pokemon change every time the user moves there mouse near it and moves around the page.
So there would be a html form with lets say 3 fields a pokemon name a pokemon id and a pokemon image. One page load it will auto grab a random pokemon from the db and fill in these hidden fields in the html form. Which i can do. Once the user moves his mouse near the pokemon/image it will move and then another random pokemon will be grabbed and the html form will change to the new pokemon info. It will keep changing till the user can click on the image which will then submit the form.

Comment: Attending to your code update, are you going to get the new images, and ids, and etc from "PHP" using AJAX? Do you k now how to that?

Comment: Well i could do it in php and i know how to do it in php but i don't know how to make the html form refresh every time the mouse goes near the image.And no i don't know how to do that use ajax to get info from php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the logic of your code above instead of button in your css and selector.

Insert a img with a specific ID.

```
<img src="" id="cantTouchThis" />
```

And use cantTouchThis in your code, your selector would like this:

```
$("#cantTouchThis").on({
```

But you are using a button and you said wanted an image, it's confusing, however. You can at any point just insert HTML after your button, like:

`$("#cantTouchThis").after('<form>.....</form>');`

Please elaborate and explain clearly for a better answer.

Tending to your update, something like this is what you want:

```
$(function(){
    $("#cantTouchThis").on({
        mouseover:function(){
            $(this).css({
                left:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
                top:(Math.random()*200)+"px",
            });
            //Go get PHP via jQuery AJAX
            // Grab data and now update your form, or insert form!
            // Insert new form $('#following_around').html('<form>...</form>');
            // Example change directly the "Pokemon" ID in the form, without the need to completely insert a new form
            $('#following_around #random_id').html(Math.random()*10);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tested the code above but image will not move... i will edit my question and try and explain better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/301/ Here is an example, everything the same, it's just an img.

Comment: Your coding now works but now i need to make it into a html form. Which refreshes every time.I have edited the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/303/ Here is an update, and above. It gets you in the right path.

Comment: One question the image is not inside the form so when the image is clicked the form is not submited. So i need to make a following_around.php which will be the grabber ?Then i need to create the random_id class in php ?I think once the image is clickable and submits the form i can go from there.,....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/304/ I have added the image into the form, if you were able to "catch" the image at some point and click it, the form would submit. You just need to replace the span with a input hidden for the pokemon ID, and look into the documentation for jQuery ajax methods such as (get,post,ajax,getJSON) so you can retrieve your info.

Comment: Thank you i click the image but nothing happens but im guessing that is because i have not checked if the form has been posted ? Thank you for all your hard work ill look into gets and posts with ajaxs.

Comment: The form does submit as is. I have updated the jsfiddle, which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDtE/311/
I added a variable to only "run away" with the picture 5 times, after that you can click it. And it does submit. ;)

Comment: So the   $("#cantTouchThis").on('click', function(e) {
       $(this).closest('form').submit();   is were the form submits ? So i can just code the form up in html and php and all should work ?Like i could make a if statement and check if its been posted ?

Comment: Yes, that submits form. Just put the values you want in your form. Go get new data from PHP via ajax and replace it. And then validate your form submission in another PHP file.